# ASP .NET 5 Beta 7 IIS deployment issues

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015

Visual Studio 2015 Deploy

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\Microsoft.DNX.Publishing.targets(150,5): Error : System.ArgumentException: The name can be no more than 260 characters in length.

XCopy - Page Load Runtime Error

> Couldn't determine an appropriate version of runtime to run. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=517742 for more information.

Comment: BTW, really need an answer here

Answer (score 0):

*Re: System.ArgumentException: The name can be no more than 260 characters in length.*

Had the same issue as above ... but found a work-around...

The work-around is to:

1) Shorten the length of the path (folders) where the ASP.NET 5 Beta 7 solution is located.

2) Shorten the name of the solution

3) Shorten the name of the web project